# Why can my program only get half of the standard input from pipe?

Tags: java

If I get the standard input from pipe like this, it is ok.

```
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        while((input=reader.readLine())!=null)
        {   
              ...
        }
```

But if I write my program like this,the BufferedReader can only get a half standard input from the pipe. The pipe will stop somewhere but the position is not certain.
And also every time I input manually line by line. The program is fine. But if I suddenly input a thousand lines. It will only output the result of the first line. I used to input only manually before so this is the first time I met this problem. I thought this two should be the same.

```
        while(true)
        {   
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            if((input=reader.readLine())==null)
            {
                break;
            }
                 ...
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BufferedReader` will read more than one line, so the next invocation can get more data without going through the operating system, which enhances performance.

If you delete the `BufferedReader` and create a new one, all the data that is already stored in the first instance is lost.

Comment: THX. I thought BufferReader only read one line once. But why my program can still get the results calculated from more than one line's input? As you said in the next loop all the data will be refreshed. Forgot to say, my program can only calculate one line's input in one loop.

Comment: When you read from a terminal, the `BufferedReader` tries to fill its entire buffer, but the terminal only returns the data entered so far, which is all complete lines entered so far. If you input each line separately and processing is fast, each instance is usually given one line because that is what is currently available. For a pipeline or a file, all the data is available at once, and the `BufferedReader` will read as much as possible.

Comment: Hi,I just tested my wrong program again. There is one thing I still can't understand. As you said the buffer read the data from the pipe as much as possible. Then my program calculated the first line and output the result.And then it should go to the next loop and refresh all the data. So there is only one line which could be calculated. However my program calculated more than one hundred lines although not completed the calculation. And I also tested to copy the one thousand lines manually and paste it on the terminal. It is just like I excepted that there is only one line's output.

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String input;
String completeInput = "";
while(true)
{   

  if((input=reader.readLine())==null)
  {
    break;
  }
    //here you need to do something with your input
    //for example
    completeInput+=input;
 }
 //here you have complete input string in complete input
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between these 2 ways of coding is very simple.

First way:

you have declared buffer reader outside the while loop like below

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

and hence for each iteration of while loop, it keeps pointing to the single same console

and hence it reads all data from the console so  is the output in right way as expected

second way:

you have declared buffer reader inside while loop like below

```
while(true)
{

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
//rest of the code

}
```

here for each iteration it creates new reader pointing to new console because of System.in assigned to reader for every while loop iteration.

so when it reads first time it reads all your lines and execute else block and prints first line because of readLine method gets only one line at a time.

and during second iteration of while loop , it points to new console and new console will not have any data so it breaks the while loop.

but if you enter line by line each while loop iteration points to new console and you enter it to new console each time and hence it prints correctly.